How to convert decimal point to comma
I need to write to a CSV file a decimal value with comma instead of decimal point dot
like
12,3
11,9
instead of 12.3 or 11.9
I am reading data from DB as 12.3 but need to write to the CSV file as 12,3.
I've tried this so far:
string s = "1.14535765";
var d = Convert.ToDecimal("1.2345", new CultureInfo("es-ES"));

But in the console I can see 12345 without any dot or comma.
I would appreciate any suggestion here. Thanks is advance
Update String to decimal conversion: dot separation instead of comma
But it doesn't solve my issue as I have already tried above the suggestions but it did not work.
The answer was given to the question to do the other way like converting comma to dot.

Are you reading a string from a database field with string type or are you converting somehow the value loaded from the database ?

Why not replace decimal point with comma directly? Something like s.Replace('.', ',').

This question is similar to: String to decimal conversion: dot separation instead of comma. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your input string has a . for the decimal separator, but when you call Convert.ToDecimal("1.2345", new CultureInfo("es-ES")) you are telling the call that the string uses , instead. So, naturally it takes the . as the thousands separator and correctly parses the string as 12345.
You need to parse the other way around, using new CultureInfo("en-US"), and then use .ToString(new CultureInfo("es-ES")) to get the Spanish version out.
Try this:
string s = "1.2345";
var d = Convert.ToDecimal(s, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
var o = d.ToString(new CultureInfo("es-ES"));
Console.WriteLine(o);

That outputs 1,2345.

Side note: reading from cache CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES") is a better choice than creating a new instance new CultureInfo("es-ES")

"es-ES" has , as decimal separator, not . (. is a group separator for it, see NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimal and NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator):
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("es-ES", false ).NumberFormat;
Console.WriteLine(nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator); // prints ","
Console.WriteLine(nfi.NumberGroupSeparator); // prints "."

Use en-US for example to parse data (or create a custom one with separator set to appropriate value):
var d = Convert.ToDecimal("1.2345", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
Console.WriteLine(d); // prints "1.2345"

Demo @dotnetfiddle
And then serialize to csv using appropriate culture (either by providing appropriate one to the serializer if it supports this, like CsvHelper does or via CultureInfo.CurrentCulture/CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture if the serializer you use does not, the second approach is show in the previous demo fiddle).

So, in this case how can I then convert 1.2345 to 1,2345?

@user7336033 you can manipulate cultures in appropriate places - use one to deserialize/read data from database and another to write/serialize to csv.

@user7336033 - You can also do "1.2345".Replace(".", ",") and avoid parsing in the first place.

The Decimal.ToString(String, IFormatProvider) method converts the numeric value of this instance to its equivalent string representation using the specified format and culture-specific format information.
decimal value = 16325.62m;
string specifier;
CultureInfo culture;

// Use standard numeric format specifiers.
specifier = "G";
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(specifier, culture));
// Displays:    16325,62

Refer to Decimal.ToString Method
